# MapBox turn by turn Custom Marker Issue

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I am using navigation view for my application, I wan to load n number markers on navigation view with different marker images. When I tried to do this with navigation annotation view only destination image is changed others shown as 1,2,3 etc.
I tried to load image using this function

```
 func navigationMapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
    let reuseIdentifier = "\(annotation.coordinate)"
    let annotationView1 = MGLAnnotationView(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    if let castAnnotation = annotation as? CustomPointAnnotation {
        annotationView1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
        let  imageV = UIImageView(frame: (annotationView1.frame))
            imageV.contentMode = .center
        imageV.image = UIImage(named: castAnnotation.image!)
        annotationView1.addSubview(imageV)
    }
    return annotationView1
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you use images in your question to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MapBox turn by turn navigation Custom Marker Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49107558/mapbox-turn-by-turn-navigation-custom-marker-issue)