# MapBox turn by turn navigation Custom Marker Issue

Tags: ios, swift3, mapbox

I am using navigation view for my application, I wan to load n number markers on navigation view with different marker images. When I tried to do this with navigation annotation view only destination image is changed others shown as 1,2,3 etc. I tried to load image using this function

```
func navigationMapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
let reuseIdentifier = "\(annotation.coordinate)"
let annotationView1 = MGLAnnotationView(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
if let castAnnotation = annotation as? CustomPointAnnotation {
    annotationView1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    let  imageV = UIImageView(frame: (annotationView1.frame))
        imageV.contentMode = .center
    imageV.image = UIImage(named: castAnnotation.image!)
    annotationView1.addSubview(imageV)
}
return annotationView1
```

}[image]

Comment: is there any way to add waypoint in navigation , if i  add more than one way points in "Directions.shared.calculate" function navigation view does not load...any help??

Comment: Have you tried adding the marker icons to Mapbox styles then calling them? This will be instead of using them as UIImages in your code.